# How does the crawler get 'click load more' data through Python

Tags: python-3.x, scraper

I am linking to the website for crawler to get pictures. At the bottom of the page, there is "click to load more". How to get the data after clicking "click to load more"?I was asked not to use selenium,

url:http://pic.haibao.com/hotimage/

Comment: From [tag:scraper] tag: "DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is under an active burnination process: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305314"

Comment: I've found a solution.thanks